# django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such column:

Tags: python, django

Please help... I am new to django.
This error occurred during running **makemigrations** after adding '**department**' in class Candidate in models

my models:

[image]

my Error:

[image]

-Thank You

Answer (score 1):

comment out whole Candidate model and then run

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate --fake
```

Then uncomment Candidate model and then run

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```